# Jquery remove link with a certain label and the whole text after this link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contain

For example:

```
<a href="/" title="Go to homepage">Homepage</a> text after link;
<a href="/" title="About">About</a> text after link;
<a href="/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a> text after link;
```

No problem: I can remove the link with:

```
$("a:contains('Homepage')").remove();
```

My question: How to remove the text after the link previously removed:

**`text after link`**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set that text node's value to empty, like this:

```
$("a:contains('Homepage')")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "";
```

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZGXpW/).  If you're unsure if it's there, add an `if` check, like this:

```
var node = $("a:contains('Homepage')")[0];
if(node && node.nextSibling) node.nextSibling.nodeValue = "";
```